# Remove X number of characters from command STDOUT

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I'm running an application that is outputing lines, piping to GREP to select only specific lines, but want to remove the first X characters which are worthless.

Specifically:

```
varnishlog | grep Hash
```

Produces for example

```
   34 Hash         c /address
   41 Hash         c /addresss?xml=1&
```

I want the last part after the "c" in order to record these in a file.

Which command do I pipe to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk works, but I think cut is simpler for this task, e.g.

```
$ varnishlog | grep Hash | cut -b 23-
```

-b specifies bytes, and 23- says keep the 23rd byte to the end of the line.

You could also use -c, which is characters instead of bytes (in this case characters == bytes)

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and came up with the following using AWK:

```
$ varnishlog | grep Hash | awk {'print substr($0,23)}'
```

This filters out the first 23 characters and leaves the part that I want.

If anyone has a better answer please post.